# How to enable a button when radio button from all the sets are selected?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I am working on a test and bumped into a problem.

How do I make a .js script that only enables button when all fields are checked.

```
<tr>
    <td class="first-col">Ritkán szorongom1
        <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="q1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" id="q1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" id="q1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" id="q1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" id="q1"></td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="first-col">Ritkán szorongom1
        <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" id="q2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" id="q2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" id="q2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="4" id="q2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" id="q2"></td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="first-col">Ritkán szorongom1
        <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" id="q3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" id="q3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" id="q3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="4" id="q3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="5" id="q3"></td>
    </td>
</tr>

<div class="register-button">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" class="inputButton" id="submit1" value="Következő" disabled id="enable-on-two" />
</div>
```

I have found this .js online, but I can't make it fit well as I have multiple pages of test questions with different input names.

```
function numberOfCheckboxesSelected() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name="seatdata[]"]:checked').length;
}

function onChange() {
    document.getElementById('enable-on-two').disabled = numberOfCheckboxesSelected() < 3;
}

document.getElementById('world').addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
```

Comment: Your code seems to try to enable the button once 2 radios are selected, but your title says _all questions_. So can you tell us exactly what behaviour you're expecting

Comment: I have left in the number 2 accidentally. I am looking for all questions to be selected than the button shall be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues with your codebase.

1. `document.getElementById('world').addEventListener('change', onChange, false);`

   **Issue** There is no node with that specified id.
2. Submit button has more than one id. That is not possible.
3. `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name="seatdata[]"]:checked')`

Your input type is `radio` so the above one wont work. Also the name attribute is wrong.

I have added those fixes.

```js
function numberOfCheckboxesSelected() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
}

function onChange() {
  console.log(numberOfCheckboxesSelected());
  document.getElementById('enable-on-two').disabled = numberOfCheckboxesSelected() < 3;
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-col">Ritkán szorongom1
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" id="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" id="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" id="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" id="q1"></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-col">Ritkán szorongom1
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" id="q2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" id="q2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" id="q2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="4" id="q2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" id="q2"></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-col">Ritkán szorongom1
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" id="q3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" id="q3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" id="q3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="4" id="q3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="5" id="q3"></td>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<div class="register-button">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" class="inputButton" value="Következő" disabled
    id="enable-on-two" />
</div>
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks your for your help. Unfortunately it does not work for me. The button does not enable even when I have checked all the boxes on the form

Comment: Initially the button was enabled when 2 radio inouts are selected. I have updated that to 3. Hope thatw ill work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution needs a little correction as it enables the submit button on two inputs selection instead of all three.

Replace following:

```
document.getElementById('enable-on-two').disabled = numberOfCheckboxesSelected() < 2;
```

By this:

```
let totalInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').length;
document.getElementById('enable-on-two').disabled = numberOfCheckboxesSelected() <   totalInputs;
```